# Adding radio button as a custom control to the Identity user in abp framework

Tags: abp

I need to add a custom controls in Identity user form using abp framework. I am able to add a dropdown using enum, but I need a radio button control.

I have added custom controls using ConfigureExtraProperties in ModuleExtensionConfigurator.cs file.

The below code is used to add a checkbox and a dropdown.

```
user.AddOrUpdateProperty<bool?>(
     "DefaultMaint"
   );
user.AddOrUpdateProperty<NotifyLevel>(
    "Notify",
    options =>
    {
        options.DefaultValue = 0;
    }
  );
```